# Single Page Application Slow to Load all Files

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application

I have been using Asp.Net Core MVC to load views and their content for several years. However, the trend seems to be pushing us strongly towards Single Page Applications (SPA). From my understanding, all html files are downloaded directly to the client. From now on we don't need to make requests to a server anymore in order to receive HTML, CSS, etc. because the routing of Vue (if configured properly) will serve the appropriate components.

All of this makes a lot of sense to me and seems like a good option. The thing I don't understand or am worried about is the loading time. Wouldn't it be extremly slow to download all files the first time when the website is called?

Comment: no. your image/media assets take the same amount of loading time as they do in server rendering. your execution time may increase in JS rendering and computations which vue do, but that is usually minimal and very subjective to what's being rendered. Third part where it may take time is the size of JS/CSS assets, but it can be reduced, if you bundle your JS correctly in chunks - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html

Comment: How do the image/media asstest take the same time? Are they not all downloaded on the initial load?

Comment: How about HTML/JS/CSS will they also all be downloaded on the initial load?

Comment: All HTML, CSS, JS isn't loaded on initial load. You can chunk your css to lazily load component by component. What this means is your product listing JS/CSS can be load when it's component is loaded and home page JS/CSS can be loaded on it's own

Comment: Thanks for the information, that makes a lot of sense now! That means I should always use lazy loading... if I don't do that it will get quite slow, I assume?

Comment: yes. I would say, be iterative. If you have clear idea about what you want to build and know the direction, you can start with lazy loading from day one. If your app building is progressive, you can see how big your assets are increasing and chunk it in logical components

Comment: For your images, it comes down to the same thing, it's loaded if the page asks for it, just like it would if you would create with a server side .NET app